# SurfaceView crashing - Why?

Tags: android, surfaceview

Right now i'm trying to test SurfaceView. It shows up in my Preview. It shows a gray background with the name of my custom SurfaceView ('RollView'). Each time i try to test it. It just crashes immediately. When i remove the com.hovanky.roll.RollView xml tag, it works. But i lose my surfaceview.  What am i doing wrong?

In xml I put in my custom SurfaceView

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.hovanky.roll.RollView
        android:id="@+id/rollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

In my activity, that extends activity. I give handles to my SurfaceView

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mRollView = (RollView) findViewById(R.id.rollview);
```

Then, I draw up a skeleton of my custom SurfaceView.

```
 class RollView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
 private SurfaceHolder holder;

 public RollView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    holder= getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your RollView class as:

```
    class RollView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
     private SurfaceHolder holder;

     public RollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder= getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
    }

    public RollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
   //your code here...
```